# How to query for empty array in JSONB?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Consider this example:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE emptyarray (fields jsonb);                                                                                                                            
CREATE TABLE                                                                                                                                                                  
postgres=# INSERT INTO emptyarray VALUES ('{"key":["a","b"]}');                                                                                                               
INSERT 0 1                                                                                                                                                                    
postgres=# INSERT INTO emptyarray VALUES ('{"key":[]}');                                                                                                                      
INSERT 0 1                                                                                                                                                                    
postgres=# SELECT * from emptyarray where Fields@>'{"key":["b"]}';                                                                                                            
       fields                                                                                                                                                                 
---------------------                                                                                                                                                         
 {"key": ["a", "b"]}                                                                                                                                                          
(1 row)                                                                                                                                                                       

postgres=# SELECT * from emptyarray where Fields@>'{"key":[]}';                                                                                                               
       fields                                                                                                                                                                 
---------------------                                                                                                                                                         
 {"key": ["a", "b"]}                                                                                                                                                          
 {"key": []}                                                                                                                                                                  
(2 rows)
```

In the second query I expected only one rows in the results (the one record with empty array). But as you can see there are two rows in the result. How do I query for a empty array using `@>` syntax?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 26):

You could use:

```
SELECT * from emptyarray where Fields-> 'key' = '[]'::jsonb;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WHU79010)**

Comment: Thanks! So, the `@>` syntax is not going to work for empty array?

Comment: @baijum Well I could not say 100% sure. I just propose alternative.

Comment: I was generating the queries, so a consistent syntax would have been easier :(

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - What if there is no key? I have a jsonb which is just an empty array like this [].